# Setting an image as an input with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

I am currently messing around with a game and i want to get an img tag to appear as a result in an input the same way i did with the Unicode character.

This is the array:

```
var wqV = [' ', '\u2613', "<img src='../images/o.png'>"];
```

here are the part of the code that sets the default as wqV[0], the user click will change it to wqV[1], and the AI is suppose to display wqV[2].

```
//listening to inputs and setting default value
inputs.forEach(function (myCl) { //myCl are the ids of the HTML
            var ele, mdiv;
            ele = UI.ById(myCl);
            mdiv = document.createElement("div");
            ele.addEventListener("click", UI.myTicFunc(myCl), false);
            mdiv.innerHTML = wqV[0];
            ele.value = (mdiv.textContent || mdiv.innerText);
        });
  // places wqV[1] anywhere the user clicks
myTicFunc: function (myCl) {
        return function () {
            var mdiv = document.createElement("div");
            mdiv.innerHTML = wqV[1];
            UI.ById(myCl).value = (mdiv.textContent || mdiv.innerText);
            UI.myAI(myCl);
        }
    }
```

UI.myAI is the function that sets wqV[2] with a bunch of nested if statements kinda like this:

```
if (sq5.value === " ") {
            sq5.value = wqV[2];
            sq5.disabled = true;
        }
```

I appreciate anyone who can spare the time to help me get that image to appear as a value.

[edit] Here is another approach i have tried.  I created a new div then gave it an id.  On my css i set the background image but it doesn't display still

```
        var myimg;
            myimg = document.createElement("div");
            myimg.id = "cpId";
            sq5.value = (myimg.textContent || myimg.innerText);

#cpId {
    background-image: url('../images/o.png');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Here is another attempt i've tried, which someone in the comments already aluded to.

```
var mimg;
    mimg = document.createElement("img");
    mimg.src = wqV[2];
    sq5.value = (mimg.textContent || mimg.innerText);
    sq5.disabled = true;
```

Comment: "image to appear as a value" - that does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Text inputs and textareas can't have an `<img>` element inside it

Comment: hmmm, then perhaps im going about this all wrong.